# Make submit from angular controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-submit

I have

```
var x = angular.element(document.getElementById('campito'[0]
       .attributes[2].submit; that show ng-submit="submit(campito)"
```

How can I trigger the submit from the controller

I have a form:

```
<form name="campito" id="campito" ng-submit="submit(campito)">
</form>
```

and a button outside de form:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sh-depth-1" form="campito" ng-disabled="!esAdmin || isLoad">
<strong>Guardar</strong>
</button>
```

Is angular 1.4.4, in chrome the button works fine, but in IE9 don´t work, I tried to change the type attribute to ng-attr-type in the button, because it is a bug, but it does not work either. Therefore what I can think of is to create a function and trigger it from the same button and within this function trigger the submit, I already get inside the function to obtain the object of the form, but I can not trigger it.
With:

```
var x = angular.element(document.getElementById('campito'))[0];
```

obtain the complete form

With:

```
var x = angular.element(document.getElementById('campito'))[0].attributes[2];
```

The ng-submit attribute.
After that I could not.

Comment: what you are willing to do on the submit? do you want to make any service call?

Comment: @aaqib, jose can you pls confirm if you have deleted some lines from the code by mistake while editing this question?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure you can see what’s been edited if you click on edited link

Comment: No, it´s ok, I´m going to explain better